# Can a child component use updateRoot: to add javascript

Tags: pharo, seaside

I'm using seaside 3.4.8 and a component [seaside-plotlyjs](https://github.com/eMaringolo/seaside-plotlyjs) to make a javascript plot. This component uses the `updateRoot:` selector to add in a link to the plotly javascript bundle. Everything is fine until I make the component a child of another component, in which case the plotly library is no longer added to the site. If I take the contents of the `updateRoot:` selector and move it into the root component, then it works again. Is it possible to have the `updateRoot:` selector be independent of whether my component is the root or a child of another one to improve the composability of my components?

`ChildComponent>>updateRoot:`

```
updateRoot: anHtmlRoot

super updateRoot: anHtmlRoot.
anHtmlRoot javascript url: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.4.2.min.js'
```

`RootComponent>>updateRoot:`

```
updateRoot: anHtmlRoot

super updateRoot: anHtmlRoot.

anHtmlRoot stylesheet url:
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css'.
anHtmlRoot stylesheet url:
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/milligram/1.4.1/milligram.css'.
```

Comment: Please include the code of your updateRoot: method in the child component

Comment: I've added in the code as you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you implement a `children` method on `RootComponent` that returns the child component ?

Seaside will use the result of the `children` method to know the component tree. A common mistake is to forget this method as many parts of Seaside work just fine without it returning all child component instances.

Comment: indeed my issue was that I had forgotten to add it as a child component in the `children` message of root.